# Skipping entire "for loop" when adding code inside the loop

Tags: c

I'm a beginner to C and have been trying to develop a few programs, but I'm currently stuck. The problem is as follows: When I run the code below, it skips over the whole "Type your name" part and skips immediately so the "Type your CPF" part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void append(char subject[], const char insert[], int pos) {
    char buf[100] = {}; 

    strncpy(buf, subject, pos); 
    int len = strlen(buf);
    strcpy(buf+len, insert); 
    len += strlen(insert);  
    strcpy(buf+len, subject+pos); 

    strcpy(subject, buf);   
}

int main() {
    int i,j;
    char name[21],filename[21],cpf[16];
    FILE *fp;

    for ( ;strlen(name)<3; ) {
        name[0] = 0;
        printf("Type your name (max characters: 20, no numbers allowed) \n");
        fflush (stdout);
        fgets(name,21,stdin);
        for(i=0; name[i]!='\0'; ++i) {
            while (!((name[i]>='a'&&name[i]<='z') || (name[i]>='A'&&name[i]<='Z' || name[i]=='\0'))) {
                for(j=i;name[j]!='\0';++j) {
                name[j]=name[j+1];
                }
            name[j]='\0';
            }
        }
        strtok(name, "\n");
        strcpy(filename,name);
        strcat(filename, ".txt");
    }
    fp = fopen(filename,"a");
    fprintf(fp,"Name:");
    fprintf(fp, name);
    fflush(stdin);

    for ( ;strlen(cpf)<11 || strlen(cpf)>11; ) {
        printf("Please enter your CPF, consisting of 11 numbers:\n");
        scanf("%s",&cpf);
    }
    append(cpf,".",3);
    append(cpf,".",7);
    append(cpf,"-",11);
    fprintf(fp,"\nCPF: ");
    fprintf(fp, cpf);
    system("pause");
}
```

However, when I comment the part below it runs normally.

```
//      for(i=0; name[i]!='\0'; ++i) {
//          while (!((name[i]>='a'&&name[i]<='z') || (name[i]>='A'&&name[i]<='Z' || name[i]=='\0'))) {
//              for(j=i;name[j]!='\0';++j) {
//                name[j]=name[j+1];
//              }
//            name[j]='\0';
//          }
//      }
```

As you can see, I want the code to remove all extra characters from the name and just make the name alphabetical characters, but I'm not sure why it skips the whole "for-loop" when I enter this particular part.

Any suggestions? Also since I'm new to C I may have included too much code, feel free to tell me and I'll remove irrelevant parts.

Comment: At the first call to `strlen(name)`, `name` is uninitialized, and it will cause an undefined behavior.

Comment: But why doesn't it do that when the outlined part isn't there? Then it asks the question.

Comment: Since you are new. .it's the perfect time to learn how to use a debugger...so that you would be able to find where the code is going haywire....also since if u do some big codes...then it would be highly helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look at these two lines:

```
char name[21],filename[21],cpf[16];
...
for ( ;strlen(name)<3; ) {
```

First you declare the array `name` (and some others), but you don't initialize it. Then you use the uninitialized in a call to `strlen`. That will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the contents of `name` is *indeterminate*.

You must explicitly initialize the array, or any other local variables, before you use it.

Simplest way is doing something like

```
char name[21] = "", ...;
```

---

As for why the code behaves differently in different situation is because of the *undefined behavior*. Undefined behavior is, by its very definition, *undefined*. It means just about anything can happen, even to *seemingly* work fine. It could also crash or cause [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: That made a lot clear, thanks a lot! I'll also start using a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You've left `name` unitialized, so `strlen(name)` is undefined behavior and seems to return `false`. To avoid this, try changing your `for` loop to a `do while` loop, which will always run once before checking the condition. This could look like:

```
do {
    //loop body that initializes name
} while (strlen(name) < 3);
```